# Udev rules matching a command's output (or something similar)

Tags: udev

I'm writing a common udev rule for deployment to computers with one or two Silicon Motion SM501 video cards installed. This is the current rule:

`TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_FOR_SEAT}=="usb-pci-*-usb-*_[34]", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0", TAG-="master-of-seat"`

I want this rule to be applied if, and only if, there's exactly **one** card present i.e. if command `lspci | grep -c SM501` outputs `1`. How could I change my rule to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I guess I've found a solution. I've just found there's a udev stanza called `RESULT` which matches the output of the last previous `PROGRAM` call. So I've updated my rule to the following one, and it seems to work:

`TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_FOR_SEAT}=="usb-pci-*-usb-*_[34]", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/lspci | /bin/grep -c SM501'", RESULT=="1", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0", TAG-="master-of-seat"`

Would it be possible to improve this rule, dropping the `/bin/sh -c '...'` wrapper in `PROGRAM`?